# Horizontal accordion div goes down when reducing the window size

Tags: jquery, accordion, horizontal-accordion

I am using a horizontal accordion based on this website:

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/accordion-common/accordion.html

If you reduce the window size the accordion will wrap down; it will not fit inside the window.

Expected :

```
 <div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
```

On a large window size this works fine, but on reducing window size, it will display like this:

```
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the `divs` from wrapping, you would really need to wrap the accordion itself in an element with defined width.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.accordionWrapper { width: 689px; }
```

Comment: I set width for the outer most div and it works.  i dont know much designing concept. one basic question . I put style="width:1024px"  is that ok. it works fine on all resolutions .

Comment: Whatever width you set it to would be fine, but I would recommend to either do a percentage-based width or the actual pixel width of the contained elements. Also, please avoid in-line styling and use external stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

It's because wrapper `div` automatically shrink when you reduce window's size.
Set width on wrapper.

```
.accordionWrapper { width: 689px; }
```

Comment: I set width for the outer most div and it works.  i dont know much designing concept. one basic question . I put style="width:1024px"  is that ok?  it works fine on all resolutions . What is the maximum width that we can give?